# Quickest way to confirm an item exists with the Core Service

Tags: core-service

I want to confirm if an item exists in Tridion with the Core Service.  I'm building a URI myself, using a parent Page item ID and the local Publication ID, and want to try to get it.

I see 2 methods available in the Core Service API that might be of help.  Which one would be the most efficient to confirm the item does exist?

```
string localUri = client.TryGetTcmUri(componentUri, publicationUri);
var page = client.TryRead(componentUri, null);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
client.IsExistingObject(uri);
```

Comment: That's a good one!